# visualizar elemento HTML colocado na página usando DOM - Javascript

Tags: javascript, dom

Classe `Piso` e classe `Consola`

```
/**
 * Classe Piso
 * contem um numero piso
 */
function Piso(id) {
    this.id = id;
}

/**
 * Classe Consola
 * contem uma lista de pisos
 */
function Consola(nome) {
    this.nome = nome;
    this.indice= -1;
    this.pisos = [];
}
```

função para inserir um `piso` na `consola`

```
/**
 * Função para inserir um piso
 * entrada: numero
 * saida: -
 */
Consola.prototype.inserirPiso = function () {
    //cria o piso apartir de zero
    var novo = new Piso(this.indice++);
    //adiciona na lista de compartimentos
    this.pisos.push(novo);
};

/**
 * Função para remover um piso
 * entrada: numero
 * saida: -
 */

Consola.prototype.remover = function (base) {
    while (base.firstChild != undefined) {
        base.removeChild(base.firstChild);
    }
}

/**
 * Função para inserir um piso
 * entrada: numero
 * saida: -
 */
Consola.prototype.criarPiso = function criarPiso() {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var btnCriar = document.createElement("button");
    var btnCriarText = document.createTextNode("Criar");
    btnCriar.appendChild(btnCriarText);
    //cria o evento
    btnCriar.onclick = function () {
        //inserir Piso
        inserirPiso();
    }
    div.appendChild(btnCriar);
    this.visualizacao.appendChild(div);

};

/**
 * Função para remover um piso
 * entrada: numero
 * saida: -
 */
Consola.prototype.removerPiso = function (indice) {
    var div = document.createElement("div");
    var btnApagar = document.createElement("button");
    var btnApagarText = document.createTextNode("Apagar");
    btnApagar.appendChild(btnApagarText);
    //cria o evento
    btnApagar.onclick = function () {
        //remover Piso
        remover(indice);
    }
    div.appendChild(btnApagar);
    this.visualizacao.appendChild(div);
};

/**
 * Função para criar novo Checkbox 
 * entrada: nome e id
 * saida: novo Checkbox 
 */

function criarCheckbox(nome, id) {
    var checkbox = document.createElement('input');
    checkbox.type = 'checkbox';
    checkbox.nome = nome;
    checkbox.id = id;
    return checkbox;
}

/**
 * Função para ver todos piso com checkbox
 * entrada: 
 * saida: todos os pisos criados
 */

Consola.prototype.verTodosPisos = function () {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.pisos.length; i++) {
        if (this.pisos[i] !== undefined) {
            this.visualizacao.appendChild(criarCheckbox("Piso" + this.pisos[i].id, this.pisos[i].id));
        }
    }
};

/**
 * Função para ver um piso
 * entrada: indice do piso
 * saida: piso
 */

Consola.prototype.verPiso = function (indice) {
    for (var i = 0; i < this.pisos.length; i++) {
        if (this.pisos[i].id === indice)
            return this.pisos[i];
    }
    return false;
};
```

a minha duvida é quando tento criar o `Piso` através de `DOM` não mostra nem os `button`criado e ao também ao chamar o `window.unload` não mostra nada na tela
penso que agora apenas falta a função para mostrar a consola na tela

função que será executada quando a página estiver toda carregada.

```
window.onload = function () {
    //chama criar piso e nao mostra nenhum dados da consola
      criarPiso(); 
}
```

o meu objectivo é implementar que ao testar, teria de ser mais ou menos, dessa forma como mostra a figura,
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Renata, te aconselho a definir um template para a Consola, e um Template para o Piso.

```
document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function () {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    // todos os elementos DOM e scripts já estão disponiveis
    // porém as imagens ainda estão à carregar.
    Consola.criarPiso();
  }
});
```

Uma pequena dica, no lugar de ficar criando elementos usando `document.createElement` e `document.createTextNode`, você pode usar a tag `template`

**HTML**

```
<template id="tmplConsola">
    <span class="consola" >Consola</span >
    <label>
        <input class="ckPiso1" type="checkbox" >
        Piso 01
    </label>
    <label>
        <input class="ckPiso2" type="checkbox" >
        Piso 02
    </label>
    <button>Criar</button>
    <button>Apagar</button>
</template>
```

**JavaScript**

```
Consola.criarPiso = function () {
    var tmpl = document.getElementById("tmplConsola");
    var elem = document.importNode(tmpl.content, true);
    document.body.appendChild(elem );    
};
```

**Edit**

Como terá N Consolas com um numero indefinido de Pisos em cada uma, é interessante que tenha um `template` para para à `Consola` e um para um `piso`

Segue abaixo um exemplo completo (execute em tela cheia).

```js
var consolas = [];
var container = null;

document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    container = document.getElementById("consolas");
    var addConsola = document.getElementById("add_consola");
    addConsola.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var consola = new Consola();;
      consolas.push(consola);
    });

  }
});

Consola = function() {
  var that = this;
  var self = this;
  this.pisos = [];
  this.dom = {};
  this.dom.card = document.importNode(this.template.content, true);
  this.dom.titulo = this.dom.card.querySelector(".mdl-card__title-text");
  this.dom.add = this.dom.card.querySelector(".piso-add");
  this.dom.remove = this.dom.card.querySelector(".piso-remove");
  this.dom.lista = this.dom.card.querySelector(".piso-list");
  this.dom.titulo.textContent = "Consola " + (++Consola.lastId);

  this.dom.add.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    that.onAddClick(event);
  });
  this.dom.remove.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    that.onRemoveClick(event);
  });

  container.appendChild(this.dom.card);
};

Consola.lastId = 0;
Consola.prototype.template = document.getElementById("tmplConsola");
Consola.prototype.onAddClick = function(event) {
  this.pisos.push(new Piso(this))
}
Consola.prototype.onRemoveClick = function(event) {
  this.pisos.forEach(function(piso, indice) {
    if (piso.selected) piso.removeSelf();
  });
}

var Piso = function(consola) {
  var that = this;

  this.consola = consola;
  this.dom = {};
  this.dom.fragment = document.importNode(this.template.content, true);
  this.dom.item = this.dom.fragment.querySelector(".piso-item");
  this.dom.sel = this.dom.item.querySelector(".piso-sel");
  this.dom.label = this.dom.item.querySelector(".piso-label");
  this.dom.sel.id = "piso_sel_" + (++Piso.lastId);
  this.dom.label.for = this.dom.sel.id;
  var texto = document.createTextNode("Piso " + Piso.lastId);
  this.dom.label.appendChild(texto);


  this.consola.dom.lista.appendChild(this.dom.item);
  componentHandler.upgradeDom();
};

Object.defineProperty(Piso.prototype, "selected", {
  get: function() {
    return this.dom.sel.checked;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    this.dom.sel.checked = value;
  }
});

Piso.lastId = 0;
Piso.prototype.template = document.getElementById("tmplPiso");
Piso.prototype.removeSelf = function() {
  var index = this.consola.pisos.indexOf(this);
  this.consola.pisos.slice(index, 1);
  this.consola.dom.lista.removeChild(this.dom.item);
  this.consola = null;
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}
.mdl-card__title {
  background-color: rgb(0, 150, 136);
}
.mdl-card__title-text {
  color: white !important;
}
.mdl-card__supporting-text {
  height: 200px;
  overflow: auto !important;
}
.mdl-card {
  width: 100%;
}
#add_consola {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}
#consolas {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.teal-red.min.css" />
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div id="consolas" class="mdl-grid">
    <h1>Sistema Domótico</h1>
  </div>
  <button id="add_consola" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
    <i class="material-icons">add</i>
  </button>
</div>

<template id="tmplConsola">
  <div class="consola mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone">
    <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Consola</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <ul class="piso-list demo-list-control mdl-list">

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__actions mdl-card--border">
        <a class="piso-add mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          Adicionar Piso
        </a>
        <a class="piso-remove mdl-button mdl-button--colored mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          Remover Piso
        </a>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="tmplPiso">
  <li class="piso-item mdl-list__item">
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
      <label class="piso-label mdl-checkbox mdl-js-checkbox mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <input type="checkbox" class="piso-sel mdl-checkbox__input" />
        
      </label>              
    </span>
  </li>
</template>
```

Comment: obrigado e esqueci de mencionar os `checkbox` deve ser dinâmico usando `DOM`

Comment: @RenataPSouza, você tem apenas uma Consola? Ou varias também?

Comment: `@TobyMosque`são varias consolas e o objetivo, pretende-se que o programa consiga lidar com inúmeras consolas, podendo-se criar consolas independentes para controlar grupos de compartimentos (ex.: ter pisos e ou anexos).

Comment: `@TobyMosque`, acho que expliquei mal a duvida e pelo que estive examinando, eu estou errado em relação a dúvida, a imagem em cima é uma consola com dois pisos criados e para apagar teria que selecionar um deles através do checkbox e depois confirmar tipo quando elimina um comentário no forum, ou seja, a primeira página será assim como mostra no link [http://imgur.com/jh2WIQn ] e a medida que ía criar o piso, ía criar um element checkbox para servir como um id do piso e desculpa foi mau a minha duvida.

Comment: @RenataPSouza, resposta atualizada.

Comment: `@TobyMosque`, já consegui resolver e muito obrigado, valeu mesmo,

Comment: `@TobyMosque`, falta apenas uma dúvida se é possível os visualizar o conteúdo do piso dentro do mesmo `container`onde é visualizado as `consolas`criadas, porque o `piso` visualizado contém `compartimentos`tipos cozinha e sala que não foram introduzidas no dúvida

Comment: @RenataPSouza, é possivel, seja alterando o label do checkbox, criando um menu ou até mesmo um dialogo. Para lhe dá uma reposta mais completa, teria que ver o layout que está tentando montar