# transição entre container principal para um novo container em Javascript usando DOM

Tags: javascript, dom

Olá, tenho um função em `Javascript` usando `DOM` para criar uma página e depois 
pretendo visualizar essa mesma pagina no `container` e para isso os dados visualizados teriam de ser apenas o pretendido e só que  container não faz um `clear`para apagar o conteudo tal como mostra na `figura 2`.

tenho esta `figura 1`, mostra a primeira página criada, fonte [visualizar elemento HTML colocado na página usando DOM - Javascript](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/127206/visualizar-elemento-html-colocado-na-p%C3%A1gina-usando-dom-javascript/127211#127211)

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e quando seleciono o `piso`e pretendo visualizar o contéudo atraves do `button` visualizar Piso e tenho o script do evento

```
/**
 * Função para visualizar dados no piso
 * 
 */
Consola.prototype.onVerClick = function (event) {
    this.pisos.forEach(function (piso, indice) {
        if ((piso.selected) &&
            (piso instanceof Piso)) {
             //chama a função
             piso.criarCompartimento(); 
        }
    });
}
```

e pretendo visualizar esta pagina dentro do mesmo `container`, como mostra a `figura 2`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

a `função` foi implementado neste script

```
/**
 * Função para criar compartimento
 */
Piso.prototype.criarCompartimento = function () {
    var h1 = document.createElement("h1")
    h1.style.color = "#ff0000";
    h1.style.textAlign = "center";

    var textoPiso = document.createTextNode("Piso " + this.id);
    h1.appendChild(textoPiso);

    var h2 = document.createElement("h2")
    h2.style.color = "#0000ff";
    h2.style.textAlign = "center";

    var textoCompartimentos = document.createTextNode("Compartimentos:");
    h2.appendChild(document.createElement("br"));
    h2.appendChild(textoCompartimentos);

    var btnCriar = document.createElement("button");
    var btnCriarText = document.createTextNode("Criar");
    btnCriar.appendChild(btnCriarText);

    var btnApagar = document.createElement("button");
    var btnApagarText = document.createTextNode("Apagar");
    btnApagar.appendChild(btnApagarText);

    var btnSistemaDom = document.createElement("button");
    var btnSistemaDomText = document.createTextNode("Sistema Domótico");
    btnSistemaDom.appendChild(btnSistemaDomText);

    container.appendChild(h1); //adicionar itens ao container
    container.appendChild(h2);
    container.appendChild(btnCriar);
    container.appendChild(btnApagar);
    container.appendChild(btnSistemaDom);
}
```

e consegui fazer apenas assim, como mostra a `figura 3`

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

e também surgiu uma outra dúvida é que se eu pretender regressar ao `container` principal `consola 1`, é possível sem perder os dados, para isso terei que criar uma nova`função`, ou criar um `evento` para um novo `button retroceder` ou existe uma outra solução?

o objetivo final é chegar pelo menos a essa estrutura, como mostra na `figura 4`, algumas paginas já foram implementas separadamente e só falta sincronizar

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: acredito que o mais simples no seu caso é abrir um dialogo que permita inserir estes dados.

Comment: E assim como eu sugeri na sua outra pergunta, evite ficar manipulando DOM para montar o layout. Ao invés disto defina um template na sua pagina e clone ele, faça isto também os Compartimentos.

Comment: de facto, tenho de seguir o enunciado ***->*** Utilize os métodos do `DOM (document.createElement` e `document.createTextNode)` para
criar os elementos necessários à página. Coloque-os, na página, através de `appendChild` e remova-os através de `removeChild`. ***Não é permitido o uso da propriedade, não standard, innerHTML.***

Comment: o dialogo para inserir dados será aberto quando eu clicar no `button criar`

Comment: eu pretendo apenas a transição `consola 1` para `piso` selecionado, sem que os dados da `consola 1` apareça, como mostra na `figura 2`

Comment: e se possível a `transição inversa` se no caso eu clicar num `button retroceder` para `consola`, são `funções` que pretendo implementar e tenho noção como fazer mas só falta aceder ao conteúdo pretendido

Comment: sobre os `compartimentos` e `equipamentos` serão ambos implementado a mesma lógica na qual foi criado as `consolas` com os `pisos`, apenas falta aceder um novo `container` com o `piso` ***selecionado*** para eu poder chamar as `funções`, ***container->consola->piso***

Comment: a pagina `index.html` apenas deve conter apenas o `container` para criar `consola e pisos` como foi implementado na outra pergunta e depois disso teremos que usar `funções` em `Javascript` para colocar os elementos na pagina e na ***fase 2*** deste projeto será elaborado em `Asp.Net MVC + Ajax`, por isso uso mais o `DOM` para gerar a `página` através dos elementos colocados.

Comment: Fico curioso o que quer dizer _"propriedade, não standard, innerHTML"_... como assim não standard?

Comment: @Sergio, acho que o AP não entendeu o metodo que sugeri, ele não faz uso do innerHTML para criar os elementos, pelo contrário, faz uso do `var node = document.importNode(template.content, true)`, ou seja, cria um novo `HTMLElement` clonando um `FragmentDocument`, de forma à evitar um reflow do html, assim obtendo uma perfomance similar ao `document.createElement` e um ganho enorme em `legibilidade`, e ainda assim estamos à usar métodos do "DOM".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Renata, segue o exemplo completo, como eu disse nos comentários, o `document.importNode` não faz uso do innerHTML, você vai está a criando e manipulando objetos DOM diretamente, ao contrario do innerHTML, onde você vai está manipulando uma string, e o browser vai precisar fazer uso do DOMParse e provocar um reflow do HTML.

```js
var consolas = [];
var container = null;
var pisoClose = null;
var dialog = {};
var pisoAtual = null;


document.addEventListener('readystatechange', function() {
  if (document.readyState == "interactive") {
    container = document.getElementById("consolas");
    dialog.wrapper = document.querySelector("dialog");
    dialog.close = dialog.wrapper.querySelector(".piso-close");
    dialog.add = dialog.wrapper.querySelector(".compartimento-add");
    dialog.desc = document.getElementById("piso_desc");
    dialog.lista = dialog.wrapper.querySelector(".compartimento-list");
    
    var addConsola = document.getElementById("add_consola");
    addConsola.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var consola = new Consola();;
      consolas.push(consola);
    });
    dialog.close.addEventListener("click", function() {
      pisoAtual = null;
      dialog.wrapper.close();
    });
    dialog.add.addEventListener("click", function() {
      var compartimento = new Compartimento(pisoAtual);
      pisoAtual.compartimentos.push(compartimento);
    });
    dialog.desc.addEventListener("input", function() {
      pisoAtual.texto = dialog.desc.value;
    });
  }
});

Consola = function() {
  var that = this;
  this.id = ++Consola.lastId;
  this.pisos = [];
  this.dom = {};
  this.dom.card = document.importNode(this.template.content, true);
  this.dom.titulo = this.dom.card.querySelector(".mdl-card__title-text");
  this.dom.add = this.dom.card.querySelector(".piso-add");  
  this.dom.lista = this.dom.card.querySelector(".piso-list");
  this.dom.titulo.textContent = "Consola " + this.id;

  this.dom.add.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    that.onAddClick(event);
  });
  

  container.appendChild(this.dom.card);
};

Consola.lastId = 0;
Consola.prototype.template = document.getElementById("tmplConsola");
Consola.prototype.onAddClick = function(event) {
  this.pisos.push(new Piso(this))
}

var Piso = function(consola) {
  var that = this;
  this.id = ++Piso.lastId;
  this.consola = consola;
  this.compartimentos = [];
  this.dom = {};
  this.dom.fragment = document.importNode(this.template.content, true);
  this.dom.item = this.dom.fragment.querySelector(".piso-item");
  this.dom.label = this.dom.item.querySelector(".piso-label");  
  this.dom.edit = this.dom.item.querySelector(".piso-edit");
  this.dom.remove = this.dom.item.querySelector(".piso-remove");  
  this.dom.button = this.dom.item.querySelector(".mdl-button");
  this.dom.menu = this.dom.item.querySelector(".mdl-menu");
  
  this.dom.button.id = "piso-button-menu-" + this.id;
  this.dom.menu.setAttribute("for", "piso-button-menu-" + this.id);
  
  this.texto = "Piso " + this.id;
  this.dom.edit.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    that.onEditClick(event);
  });
  this.dom.remove.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    that.onRemoveClick(event);
  });
  this.consola.dom.lista.appendChild(this.dom.item);
  componentHandler.upgradeDom();
};

Object.defineProperty(Piso.prototype, "texto", {
  get: function() {
    return this.dom.label.textContent;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    this.dom.label.textContent = value;
  }
});

Piso.lastId = 0;
Piso.prototype.template = document.getElementById("tmplPiso");
Piso.prototype.onRemoveClick = function(event) {
  var index = this.consola.pisos.indexOf(this);
  this.consola.pisos.splice(index, 1);
  this.consola.dom.lista.removeChild(this.dom.item);
  this.consola = null;
}
Piso.prototype.onEditClick = function(event) {
  pisoAtual = this;
  dialog.desc.value = pisoAtual.texto;
  dialog.desc.parentElement.classList.toggle("is-dirty", pisoAtual.texto);  
  // limpando a lista.
  while (dialog.lista.firstChild) {
    dialog.lista.removeChild(dialog.lista.firstChild);
  }  
  this.compartimentos.forEach(function (compartimento, indice) {
    dialog.lista.appendChild(compartimento.dom.item);
  });
  dialog.wrapper.showModal();
}

var Compartimento = function(piso) {
  var that = this;
  this.id = ++Compartimento.lastId;
  this.piso = piso;
  this.dom = {};
  this.dom.fragment = document.importNode(this.template.content, true);
  this.dom.item = this.dom.fragment.querySelector(".compartimento-item");
  this.dom.label = this.dom.item.querySelector(".compartimento-label"); 
  this.dom.remove = this.dom.item.querySelector(".compartimento-remove"); 
  
  
  this.texto = "Compartimento " + this.id;
  this.dom.remove.addEventListener("click", function(event) {
    that.onRemoveClick(event);
  });
  dialog.lista.appendChild(this.dom.item);
  componentHandler.upgradeDom();
};

Object.defineProperty(Compartimento.prototype, "texto", {
  get: function() {
    return this.dom.label.textContent;
  },
  set: function(value) {
    this.dom.label.textContent = value;
  }
});

Compartimento.lastId = 0;
Compartimento.prototype.template = document.getElementById("tmplCompartimento");
Compartimento.prototype.onRemoveClick = function(event) {
  var index = this.piso.compartimentos.indexOf(this);
  this.piso.compartimentos.splice(index, 1);
  this.piso = null;
  dialog.lista.removeChild(this.dom.item);  
}
```

```css
html,
body {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0px;
  background-color: whitesmoke;
}

.mdl-layout__header {
  height: 40px !important;
  display: block !important;
}

.mdl-card__title {
  background-color: rgb(0, 150, 136);
}
.mdl-card__title-text, .mdl-card__menu .piso-add i {
  color: white !important;
}
.mdl-card__supporting-text, .mdl-dialog__content, .mdl-layout__content {
  overflow: auto !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
}
.mdl-card__supporting-text {  
  overflow: hidden !important;
  padding: 0px !important;
  width: 100% !important;
}
.piso-list.mdl-list, .compartimento-list.mdl-list {
  height: 200px;
  margin: 0px !important;
  overflow: auto !important;
}
.mdl-card {
  width: 100%;
}
.mdl-list__item-secondary-content div {
  float: left;
}
dialog {
  width: 320px !important;
}
#add_consola {
  margin: auto;
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 10px;
  right: 10px;
  z-index: 2;
}
#container {
  position: absolute;
  top: 0px;
  right: 0px;
  bottom: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  margin: auto;
  background-color: white;
  width: 100%;
  max-width: 1080px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 10px black;
}
#consolas {
  position: relative;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  overflow: auto;
  z-index: 1;
  padding: 0px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/icon?family=Material+Icons">
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.teal-red.min.css" />
<script defer src="https://code.getmdl.io/1.1.3/material.min.js"></script>

<div id="container">
  <div class="demo-layout-transparent mdl-layout mdl-js-layout">
    <header class="mdl-layout__header mdl-layout__header--scroll">
      <div class="mdl-layout__header-row">
        <span class="mdl-layout-title">Sistemas Domóticos</span>
      </div>
    </header>
    <main class="mdl-layout__content">
      <div id="consolas" class="mdl-grid">        
      </div>          
    </main>
    <button id="add_consola" class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--fab mdl-js-ripple-effect mdl-button--colored">
      <i class="material-icons">add</i>
    </button>
  </div>
</div>
<dialog class="mdl-dialog">
  <h4 class="mdl-dialog__title">Editar Piso</h4>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__content">
    <div class="mdl-textfield mdl-js-textfield mdl-textfield--floating-label">
      <input class="mdl-textfield__input" type="text" id="piso_desc">
      <label class="mdl-textfield__label" for="piso_desc">Descrição</label>
    </div>
    <ul class="compartimento-list demo-list-control mdl-list">

    </ul>
  </div>
  <div class="mdl-dialog__actions">
    <button type="button" class="piso-close mdl-button">Fechar</button>
    <button type="button" class="compartimento-add mdl-button">Add Compartimento</button>
  </div>
</dialog>

<template id="tmplConsola">
  <div class="consola mdl-cell mdl-cell--4-col mdl-cell--6-col-tablet mdl-cell--12-col-phone">
    <div class="mdl-card mdl-shadow--2dp">
      <div class="mdl-card__title mdl-card--expand">
        <h2 class="mdl-card__title-text">Consola</h2>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__supporting-text">
        <ul class="piso-list mdl-list">

        </ul>
      </div>
      <div class="mdl-card__menu">
        <button class="piso-add mdl-button mdl-button--icon mdl-js-button mdl-js-ripple-effect">
          <i class="material-icons">add</i>
        </button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<template id="tmplPiso">
  <li class="piso-item mdl-list__item">
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
      <span class="piso-label"></span>             
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
      <button class="mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon">
        <i class="material-icons">more_vert</i>
      </button>
      <ul class="mdl-menu mdl-menu--bottom-right mdl-js-menu mdl-js-ripple-effect">
        <li class="piso-edit mdl-menu__item">Editar</li>
        <li class="piso-remove mdl-menu__item">Excluir</li>
      </ul>
    </span>
  </li>
</template>

<template id="tmplCompartimento">
  <li class="compartimento-item mdl-list__item">
    <span class="mdl-list__item-primary-content">
      <span class="compartimento-label"></span>             
    </span>
    <span class="mdl-list__item-secondary-content">
      <button class="compartimento-remove mdl-button mdl-js-button mdl-button--icon mdl-button--colored">
        <i class="material-icons">delete_forever</i>
      </button>
    </span>
  </li>
</template>
```